# Showing PHP output continuously?

Tags: php

I have a script that runs for like 1 hour.
I have 2 webhosts, in one of them, I can see the output in realtime, (it loops a million times and echoes stuff) while on the other webhost, I have to wait until the script is finished running before I see any output at all.

How can I change the settings to show the output in realtime? I guess this is a php.ini thing.

Adding code: This code will output while executing in the first server, but not in the second server. Additional info, if i put the value of 1015 lower, the first server waits with outputting. So it seems that my first server is flushing every 1015 characters, while the second does not.

```
while ($a++ < 5) {
  $b = 0;
  while ($b++ < 1015) {
    echo "H";
  }
  echo "<br><br>\n";
  sleep(1);
}
```

On my second server, output buffering is off, and i tried turning on implicit_flush to no avail.

Answer (score 10):

This is related to output buffering. If output buffering is turned on, the output is not sent to the client immediately but will wait until a certain amount of data buffered. This usually increases performance but will cause problem like yours.

The simple solution doesn't require changing any `php.ini` settings, but simply put this at the beginning of your script:

```
<?php
  while (@ob_end_flush());
?>
```

This will flush and disable all output buffering at once.

(Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php#example-460)

You may also want to read the PHP manual on [Output Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). The related `php.ini` settings are listed [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).

If you want to make sure things are being sent (i.e. before a time-consuming task), call [`flush()`](http://www.php.net/flush) at the appropriate times.

---

**Edit:**

In fact browsers may have their own buffers, especially when Content-Type is not explicitly set (the browser need to sniff the MIME-type of the file). If this is the case, you cannot control the browser's behaviour.

One way that might solve it is to explicitly set the Content-Type:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); // if you don't need HTML
// OR
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

But this is **not** guaranteed to work. It works on my Firefox but not [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31410).

Anyway, your final code should look like:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html"); // Set Content-Type
while (@ob_end_flush()); // Flush and disable output buffers
while ($a++ < 5) {
  $b = 0;
  while ($b++ < 1015) {
    echo "H";
    //flush(); // In fact because there is no significant delay, you should not flush here.
  }
  echo "<br><br>\n";
  flush(); // Flush output
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: guess i need the php.ini stuff, flushing did not do anything for me on that server.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth Web browsers may also have their own buffering, so this may not always be a server-side problem.

Comment: but im using the same script, and the same session in the same browser and running both scripts at the same time, on the different servers. and one displays the output right away, the other doesnt.

Comment: done. i give up for now, ill try contacting my webhost monday.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth See my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling [`flush`](http://www.php.net/flush) periodically. If you are using [output buffering](http://www.php.net/outcontrol), you may want to turn that off with a sequence of [`ob_end_flush`](http://www.php.net/ob_end_flush) or use [`ob_flush`](http://www.php.net/ob_flush) as well.

Comment: nothing worked on my second server. i guess the server is overriding some settings.